# The Dimension of the Logistic Map (Fractal & Topological)

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I'm a high school student doing my math IA on fractal dimensions.

According to this [Wikepedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map), the logistic map's correlation dimension, Hausdorff dimension, and information dimension are all roughly 0.5. However, since the logistic map is made up of a bunch of lines, I assume its topological dimension is 1. How, then, can its fractal dimension be *less* than this?

I also found another [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension) stating that the aforementioned Hausdorff dimension is actually that of the Feigenbaum *attractor*, which seems to me to be 0 dimensional. This makes more sense, but somewhat contradicts the first link.

What's going on here? Is the topological dimension of the logistic map 0 or 1, and is ~0.5 the dimension of the entire map or just the Feigenbaum attractor?

UPDATE #1: I realized that *both* Wikepedia pages are only talking about the dimension at a specific r value (which is 0-dimensional topologically). That should solve the above questions. Does anybody know if a fractal dimension of the entire bifurcation diagram has been found? To my knowledge there's nothing.

Comment: The bifurcation diagram (looks like lines) of the logistic map and the logistic map ($x \to r x (1 - x)$) are not the same thing.  I think that paragraph of the first Wikipedia article refers to a particular fixed value of $r$, so the dimension would be of one vertical slice through the bifurcation diagram, which would look like a bunch of points.  The second Wikipedia article refers to a particular $r$ value (vertical slice of the diagram) too.

Comment: You're right, I didn't see the "for r ≈ 3.5699456". Thank you!